# Bootstrap generated HTML files not rendering CSS in PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, centos7

I am trying to convert HTML file to PDF file using wkhtmltopdf and it is creating file correctly but missing all bootstrap related styles.

BELOW IS LINUX COMMAND TO CONVERT HTML TO PDF:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf $htmlFile $pdfFile
```

The application is HTTPS enabled and all HTML files are SOURCING as HTTPS as BELOW:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Any help is appreciated since i am stuck and not sure why bootstrap style is not loading correctly.

Comment: add the domains and their IPs to your host file?

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2120

what error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf does not work well with Bootstrap. If you search the internet you will find that some suggest to explicitly set the viewport size (this seems to fix it for some versions). Add this to your command:

--viewport-size 1024x768

In your case you would get:

xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --viewport-size 1024x768 $htmlFile $pdfFile

Another (the best I found) explanation is that Bootstrap has all col-xx-n classes inside media queries except for the col-xs-n class. Add the col-xs-n class to all elements might solve your problems. For me that solved the problems except for dynamically generated content (using jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

It's rather that `wkhtmltopdf` had problem with linked CSS and JS files. You want to inline all the desired CSS and JS! It's hard to give a code example for that, it depends on your back-end / server side.